# How can I get an Excel generated email to auto fill the subject with a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get Excel to auto fill the subject line with a specific cell value when an email is generated.
Currently My code for the email process is:

```
Sub EmailStage1Answers()
'
' EmailStage1Answers Macro
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Copy of " & wb1.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "EMAIL HIDDEN FOR POSTING"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Assessment Form, Stage 1 ***INSERT PROJECT NAME***"
    .Body = "Please see the latest copy of the Assessment Form attached.  NOTE: Please ensure you have inserted the project name above."
    .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

The workbook has a total of 19 pages and I want to populate the subject from a specific cell on the third page.
Can anyone advise?

Comment: I don't know if it is applicable, but have you looked at mail merge in word? It will do exactly this. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Comment: `Subject = "Assessment Form, Stage 1 " & Thisworkbook.Worksheets("<sheet name here>").Range("<cell reference here>").Value`

Comment: Page number is of no use, unless you mean there are 19  SheetNames.  Also, you need specific Row & Column as <cell reference> as per Zac above.